# Split out array list into separate strings

Tags: java, android, arrays, sqlite

I have created an array of values from my SQLite database - this comprises of just two values from two different columns from an inner joined table.

in my SQLDatabaseHelper.java:

```
public List<List<String>> getAllAnswersByQuestion1() {
    List<String> array1 = new ArrayList<String>();  
    List<String> array2 = new ArrayList<String>();  

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ANSWERS + " ta, "
            + TABLE_QUESTION + " tq, " + TABLE_QUESTANS + " tqa WHERE  ta." + ASID
            + " = " + "tqa." + ASID + " AND tq." + QID + " = "
            + "tqa." + QID;

   Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
   if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    do {

     String questdescr = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QDESCR));
     String questid = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QID));
     array1.add(questdescr);
     array2.add(questid);

    } while (c.moveToNext());

 }
   List< List<String> > listArray = new ArrayList< List<String> >();
   listArray.add(array1);
   listArray.add(array2);

   return listArray;

}
```

I want to pass these to my main activity. Specifically I would like to split out the array into separate strings so I can assign those values to separate edittext fields.

This is my current attempt in my main activity:

```
    public void showNextRandomQuestion()
    {
    SQLDatabaseHelper db = new SQLDatabaseHelper(this);

    StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(db.getAllAnswersByQuestion1(), ",");
    String first = tokens.nextToken();
    String second = tokens.nextToken();

    questionView.setText(first);
    answerText1.setText(second);
    }
```

However the code will not compile as it wants to either 'change the return type of 'getAllAnswersByQuestion1() to string' - or 'Remove argument to match StingTokenizer(String)'

Can't seem to get around this.

Comment: That's because `StringTokenizer` expects a `String` and you're passing a `List<List<String>>`

Comment: The array _already_ consists of separate strings. What more do you want to do with it? You only have two edit fields, and lots of strings. Doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(List l : db.getAllAnswersByQuestion1()){
           for(String s : l){
                StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(s, ",");
        String first = tokens.nextToken();
        String second = tokens.nextToken();

        questionView.setText(first);
        answerText1.setText(second);
           }
 }
```

this update will make your code work at least

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have both the question and answer stored in the `QDESCR` field, comma delimited.

If that is the case, then something like the code below would work.
I assume that you want to select a random question from the list, given the method name.

You can use `Random` in order to generate a random index of the list.
You might want to add logic to prevent previously selected questions from coming up again.

Here is the basic code that gets the question/answer, and question ID:

```
public void showNextRandomQuestion() {

    //get the data from the database
    List<List<String>> listList = db.getAllAnswersByQuestion1();

    //Get the question/answer Strings and the question IDs
    List<String> questionStrings = listList.get(0); //question and answer Strings
    List<String> questionIDs = listList.get(1); //question IDs

    //Generate random index
    Random r = new Random();
    int rand = Math.abs((r.nextInt() % questionStrings.size()));

    //get question ID for randomly selected question
    String questionID = questionIDs.get(rand);

    //Separate out the question/answer of randomly selected question
    StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(questionStrings.get(rand), ",");

    String first = tokens.nextToken();
    String second = tokens.nextToken();

    questionView.setText(first);
    answerText1.setText(second);
}
```

Also, note that it would be better to use `String.split()`, as is stated in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/StringTokenizer.html).